# Wireless RGB-D Image Streaming experience lagging

Tags: ros, network, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings. I already optimized the wireless image streaming.

The frames are being transmitted by 10fps @ 320x240 resolution. Depth is compressed in PNG while Color is compressed in JPG. I measured their bandwidth by using rostopic bw and I get 450+ kB/s.

There was no lag and it was smooth sailing but suddenly, after few more testing, it began lagging and soon stopped sending images.

Though RGB still send, the depth stopped.

What could possibly be the problem? Is it the Wi-Fi router? Is it the image transport encapsulation? Or is it the driver?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190665/wireless-rgb-d-image-streaming-experience-lagging./) by [Xegara](https://answers.ros.org/users/14401/xegara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2014-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First port of call I'd try using ros_topic bw /*topic_name* might shed some light on what is really being sent.

Sorry need a bit more info really to help further

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0